# Only match characters (case insensitive) and numbers, no spaces or special characters

Tags: regex

Having issues with the current regex (java):

```
^[\w]*$
```

Wanted to negate the `_` (underscore character). The overall goal would be to capture:

1. Characters (uppercase and lowercase allowed);
2. All numbers allowed;

Not allowed:

1. Spaces;
2. Special characters (`!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\[\]:;'",\-`  etc);
3. Accented characters (`á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡` etc);

Can you assist please?

Francisco Ramilo

Comment: Try `"^[\\w&&[^_]]*$"`.

Comment: Or if you plan to only support ASCII letters and digits, just use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`.

Comment: Looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html I think `^[\p{Alnum}]*$` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You may use negative lookahead to exclude some character ('_' here):

```
^(?:(?!_)\w)*$
```